# Direct to different component on click of url on leaflet popup in svelte

Tags: arrays, leaflet, svelte

I am trying to add the url to the the leaflet popup. The idea is to add the url which can take me to other component in the svelte. Basically route to another component.

Here is the pop up In a component named "Details"

```
 L.marker([pos.x,pos.y],{icon: greenIcon})
      .addTo(layerGroup)
      .bindPopup("X: " + pos.x + "," + "Y: " + pos.y )
      .openPopup();
```

App.svelte is like below

```
<script>
    import { Router, Link, Route } from "svelte-routing";
    import Configuration from './routes/Configuration.svelte';
    import Details from './routes/Details.svelte';
    
    export let url = "";
  </script>
  
  <style>
   ..... 
</style>
  <Router url="{url}">
    <nav>
      <Link to="/">Details</Link>
      <Link to="Configuration">Configuration</Link>
    </nav>
    <div class="main">
      <Route path="/"><Details /></Route>
    <Route path="Configuration" component="{Configuration}" />
    </div>
  </Router>
```

How can I add the url to the bindpopup in Details.svelte such that when this url is clicked it directs me to Configuration.svelte?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this but you will lose the client-side routing.

Leaflet's popup supports HTML inside `bindPopup` [method](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.7.1.html#layer-bindpopup)

```js
 L.marker([pos.x,pos.y],{icon: greenIcon})
      .addTo(layerGroup)
      .bindPopup(`X: ${pos.x}, Y: ${pos.y}
      <br> <a href="/configuration">Click here to go to Configuration page</a>` )
      .openPopup();
```

*Also a slight modification to your message inside the `bindPopup` you can avoid having to concatenate strings with `+` instead you can use [template strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)*

To your start script add `--single`

```js
  "scripts": {
    "build": "rollup -c",
    "dev": "rollup -c -w",
    "start": "sirv public --single"
  },
```

**EDIT 1:**

There is another method to preserve the client-side routing a combination of `DomUtil` and `navigate` from svelte-routing can achieve this.

```js
  import { navigate } from "svelte-routing";


  let content = L.DomUtil.create("div", "myPopup");
  content.innerHTML = `X: ${pos.x}, Y: ${pos.y}
      <br> <a href="/configuration">Click here to go to Configuration page</a>`;

  L.marker([pos.x,pos.y],{icon: greenIcon})
      .addTo(layerGroup)
      .bindPopup(content)
      .openPopup();

   content.onclick = (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      navigate("/", { replace: true });
    };
```